# Why is removing the necessary "}" generates error, yet having it wrong renders page correctly[vue js]?

Tags: vuejs2, syntax-error

I'm following the tutorial, making punchbag game [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WjfpQlVem-8&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9gQcYgjhBoeQH7wiAyZNrYa&index=13). I did everything correctly.

```
    new Vue({
el:'#punch_game',
data:{
  health:100,
  ended:false
},
methods:{
  punch:function(){
    this.health-=10;
    if(this.health <=0){
      this.ended=true;
    }
  },
  restart:function(){
    this.health=100;
    this.ended=false;    
  }
}
} <---- REMOVING THIS NEEDED bracket MAKES THE Vue instance incomplete, but renders page fine! 
  <------Keeping it stops vue from rendering page altogether! Why?
);
```

It gives this image, the console does indicate error, the **needed** bracket is **missing** - but at least I can see some buttons and the Vue DOES RENDER fine!

[image: kk]

Here, I have the **correct** brackets in main.js - vue instance is **complete** with all brackets, but it makes everything disappear and this error message shows up:

[image: kk]

Zoomed in:

```
    vue.js:597 [Vue warn]: Failed to generate render function:

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in

    with(this){return _c('div',{attrs:{"id":"punch_game"}},[_c('div',{staticClass:"{burst:ended}",attrs:{"id":"bag","":}})
,_v(" "),_c('div',{attrs:{"id":"bag_health"}},[_c('div',{style:({width:health + '%'})})]),_v(" "),_c('div',{attrs:{"id":"controls"}}
,[_c('button',{directives:[{name:"show",
rawName:"v-show",value:(!ended),expression:"!ended"}]
,on:{"click":punch}},[_v("punch")]),_v(" "),_c('button',{on:{"click":restart}},[_v("restart")])])])}


    (found in <Root>)
```

This is a mysterious heisen bug..

Comment: Are you sure this is *all* the code you have on your page? That is because based on what I can see, the code you posted is correct. Can you create a minimal, concrete, and verifiable example using the code snippet?

Comment: @Terry, ok, i did not post the html & css :))  u mean in gist?

Comment: Just post it as a code snippet. Or in a Jsfiddle, where we can actually test your code out itself (gist does not have previews).

Comment: @Terry, thx u Terry! i 'm also exploring js fiddle feature "collaborate" , did not know it! here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bogbocwn/14/

Comment: @Terry, i have added 2 images of punch bag as url resources in CSS file in url(...)

Comment: @Terry, if u look at the CSS part , u would see the red dot - the bracket causes error, but Vue renders properly..

Comment: if it's deleted, the error goes away, but Vue stop rendering at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your fiddle, but the error comes from the white-space in your incorrect v-bind use:

```
<div id="bag" v-bind: class="{burst:ended}"></div>
```

There should not be any whitespace between `v-bind:` and `class`. Also, if you want to render the width in percentages, I guess you should be using `v-bind:style="{ width: health + '%' }"` instead of `health - '%'`?

Your fiddle is also broken because you are loading incorrect resources (I don't see why including a HTML page will do anything), and also JSFiddle already wraps all your markup in `<body>` element, so you can't simply copy and paste the entire `<html>` markup of your page into it.

See your fixed fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/bogbocwn/24/

Comment: omg! thx u Terry! who might have noticed this whitespace bug?! this is +10% to my future senior level coding! thx u so much! SO rocks!

Comment: i would have never looked into v-bind itself! I take my hat off!

Comment: actually the tutorial never mentions the whitespace btw v-tag and class.. it's this subtle things I sometime hate coding for!

Comment: i also found amazing alternative to js fiddle - codesandbox. io, must check out!

Comment: the bag still does not change its image, when the health bar goes to 0. even though I see how it changes its class in CSS( #bag .burst) still not working. https://jsfiddle.net/vjr1x7f7/14/

Comment: I figured it out! I just put the stupid whitespace in btw #bag .burst